# Current marker distance to map bounds

Tags: google-maps-api-3, google-maps-markers, distance

i need the current distance between the marker and the map bounds to decide: draw the tipbox left, right, over or under the marker.

I set the position of the tipbox with these lines of code:

```
Label.prototype.draw = function() {
  var projection = this.getProjection();
  var position = projection.fromLatLngToDivPixel(this.get('position'));

  // position of tipbox, depends on margin to map boaunds
  var div = this.div_;
  var mapWidth = parseInt($('#mapBox').css('width'));
  var mapHeight = parseInt($('#mapBox').css('height'));

  div.style.left = (position.x-(parseInt(div.style.width)/2)) + 'px';
  div.style.top = position.y + 'px';      
  div.style.display = 'inline';

  $('.tipBox-inner').html(''+position.x);
};
```

But if i drag the page, the position.x or position.y return the same number of pixels. As you can see on the image, the x position is at 300px(!). I would draw the tipbox in top of the marker, if the marker is at the bottom of page and so on.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Ok i found a solution myself. I get the distance(px) to margin in the mouseover-Event of the marker:

```
google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'mouseover', function(event) {    
  label = new Label({
    map: map
  });

  label.bindTo('position', marker, 'position');

  var pixel = label.getProjection().fromLatLngToContainerPixel(event.latLng);

  label.set('mouseX', pixel.x);
  label.set('mouseY', pixel.y);
});
```

Now i can use mouseX and mouseY in draw-functionf of the Label with this.get('mouseX')